# get localStorage value automatically when a tab is open or activated

Tags: javascript, window, focus

I need to set a localStorage item on `tags.php` and get its updated value automatically when user switch to `index.php`.

**tags.php**

```
$(document).on('click', '.tagdown', function() {
    var a = $('#tagsup').html();
    localStorage.setItem('tags', a);
});
```

**index.php**
here I need something like this:

```
$(window).onfocus(function(){
console.log(localStorage.getItem('tags'));
});
```

but `$(window).onfocus()` - doesn't exist.

I tried with `body.onfocus` doesn't work in case a body-child element has focus.

Any help.

Comment: [MDN: Responding to storage changes with the StorageEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `focus` not `onfocus`:

```
$(window).focus(function(){
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('tags'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) event for this like:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).focus(function() {
        console.log('Window is in focus');
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('tags'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `on` and focus on window, instead of onfocus. **`on`** works on dynamically created elements as well.

```js
jQuery(window).on('focus',  function(e){
        console.log("focused on " + $(e.target));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click anywhere in the window
```